# I can't properly set permissions to MySQL config files

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Yesterday I ran out of hard drive space for the database in the middle of a dump; Luckily this was in development and I had my backups... but I like to see these cases in detail and document them in case it happens in production.

It happens that the MySQL server got corrupted; and it requires a re-install after purging the system it seems my personal configurations or some of mysql were not deleted.

So I get this Warning:

> Sep 27 09:13:10 ubuntu-server-vm mysql-systemd-start[2027]:
> my_print_defaults: [Warning] World-writable config file
> '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored. Sep 27 09:13:10 ubuntu-server-vm
> mysqld[2048]: mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file
> '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.

I have done some research to solve it personally and found this answer:

[How to solve “Warning: World-writable config file ‘/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf’ is ignored” in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788774/how-to-solve-warning-world-writable-config-file-opt-lampp-etc-my-cnf-is-ign)

***I have tried all of the following:***

1. change the user who owns the file:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

2. change the write and read permission of the file:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

try different types of permissions below `777`:  `775`, `755`, `644` y `600`.

***the result is still the same:***

[image]

if I put permission `777` then it works:

[image]

Still, that warning bothers me.

***What other things should I check to fix it?***

Comment: The morale of the story:  Always keep half the disk free.

Comment: @RickJames sure.

Answer (score 0):

when validating the content of the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` i get this:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

valid that all the files exist and the first file/directory is missing, it occurred to me to proceed to comment it like this:

```
#!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

apply the procedure again with `644` permissions and restart the server, and everything works fine now with no warnings.

Comment: Or, `.../conf.d/` needs to be `mysql:mysql` and `600`.  I see `root:root` and `755` on my machine.  Either should work.

Comment: @RickJames  I tray that and not work, is part of the other solution change the owner...